# Responsive css grid image gallery

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a responsive css grid image gallery. I have 18 divs in my html inside of a container. I have given them different classes. The first problem I am having is that I want to span the first image with a class of vertical. As you can see in my css i have added  grid-column: span 2; to the class .vertical. When I do that the image spans over two columns but the image resizes and gets bigger both vertically and horizontally. I only want to span it horizontal over two grids. Now to the second problem. When i use grid-row:span 2 on the image with a class of .vertical, the image beneath moves up but the image with a class of vertical doesen't span vertically at all. I will provide my code beneath. Thank you for any guidence.

```css
img{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}

 .container{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
   grid-gap: 5px;
   
  
 }

 
 .horizontal{
  grid-column:span 2;
 
}
.vertical{
 grid-row:span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="horizontal"><img src="christian.jpg"></div>
     <div class="vertical"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="tva"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
       <div class="tre"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
       <div class="fyra"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
       <div class="fem"><img src="5.jpg"></div>
       <div class="sex"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
       <div class="sju"><img src="7.jpg"></div>
       <div class="vertical"><img src="christian.jpg"></div>
       <div class="ett"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
       <div class="tva"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
       <div class="tre"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
       <div class="fyra"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
       <div class="fem"><img src="5.jpg"></div>
       <div class="sex"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
       <div class="sju"><img src="7.jpg"></div>
       <div class="sex"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
       <div class="sju"><img src="7.jpg"></div>
       
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vvcB.png)

Comment: Try changing the image to `max-width:100%` - Otherwise you are forcing it.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your provided code is the `width: 100%` property you've set for `img`. Changing it to `max-width` won't allow the images to expand outside of the columns/rows. I also added `object-fit: cover` to `img` so that they fill the space appropriately.

```css
img{
    object-fit: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
   grid-gap: 5px;
}

.horizontal{
   grid-column: span 2;
}
.vertical{
   grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="horizontal"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/500"></div>
     <div class="vertical"><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/1000"></div>
      <div class="tva"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="tre"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="fyra"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="fem"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="sex"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="sju"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="vertical"><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/1000"></div>
       <div class="ett"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="tva"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="tre"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="fyra"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="fem"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="sex"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="sju"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="sex"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       <div class="sju"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400"></div>
       
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```